# Unexpected Error using fprintf

Tags: matlab

I'm confused why I am getting this error. When i open a new file and run my code, it runs smoothly but if i open the same file the next day or later in the same day, I get this error.

[image: Error Image]

```
works = cd;
t=(now);
s2 = datestr(t,'-FFF');
s3 = 6;
ind = [s2,s3];
try
    Zahler=[works,'zahler.txt'];
    fza=fopen(Zahler,'r');
    gen=fscanf(fza,'%8i');
    try
        Test = 1/gen;
    catch
        gen = 1;
    end
    gen=gen+1;
    fclose (fza);
    fza=fopen(Zahler,'w');
    fprintf(fza,'%8i',gen);
    fclose (fza);

catch
    Zahler=[works,'zahler.txt'];
    fza=fopen(Zahler,'w');
    gen = 0;
    fprintf(fza,'%8i',gen);% This is the error line
end
```

I would be happy if anyone let me know how can i fix this permanently.

Comment: I think this should help: https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/252473-error-using-fprintf-invalid-file-identifier-use-fopen Short summary: close your files before reopening them  in the same matlab session using `fclose(fza);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the exception occurred before closing the file, you get this error. So, you should check if the previous file opening has not been closed, you should close it first. Then reopen the file and do what you want. Also, you should remember to close the file at the end of `catch` scope. To do this, it would be better to use `fclose('all')` to be sure that all open files are closed at the beginning of the `catch` scope like the following:

```
try
% ...
catch
    fclose('all');
    Zahler=[works,'zahler.txt'];
    fza=fopen(Zahler,'w');
    gen = 0;
    fprintf(fza,'%8i',gen);% This is the error line
    fclose(fza);
end
```